# Change display in form to another form in j2me

Tags: java-me, midp, lcdui

I get trouble when I created one form and one midlet and I want through an alert for user when user enters detail, but I got trouble it can't change screen to show alert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nothing can be easier with the code provided in [rev 4 of your question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/7455351/4)

```
// ... your AddReview class

    public AddReview(String title, MainFoodie mf) {
        super(title);
        this.mf = mf; // without that you'll get NPE in changeSreen
        // ...
    }

    //...
    private void changeScreen(Alert a, Form f){
        Display.getDisplay(mf).setCurrent(a, f);
    }

    public void commandAction(Command c, Displayable d) {
       if(c.getLabel().equals("Save")){
           // how to show alert here:
           changeScreen(cfmAlert, this)
       }
```

Comment: Where changescreen function? in midlet or on my AddReview class?

i try it but i cant do it, it's give me null pointer exception !

Comment: @MYE in `AddReview` class. It gives you NPE because of bug in your code: `mf` is not initialized. Pass the non-null instance of `mf` via `AddReview` constructor. Or better yet, just pass Display object